# can't ever vs can never

Tags: word-choice, negation

> I can never win.

Or

> I can't ever win.

Can these be used interchangeably? Is there a case where one would work and the other wouldn't?

Comment: Yes. They both mean the same thing (_I can not ever win_) and they are both formed by contraction of the _not_, with one crucial difference: _I can never win_ contracts _not_ and _ever_, while _I can't ever win_ contracts _not_ and _can_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grammatically, they are absolutely interchangeable. Any advantage in one over the other would be a question of style.

In *I can never win*, the "n" in "never" stands for the negative "not". In *I can't ever win*, the "n't" in "can't" stands for the same negative "not". The effective statement in both formulas is the negative **I can not win** with "ever" modifying "win" as an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

"never" is a simple statement of fact, 
whereas "not ever"  says that it is a stronger command or statement.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! This answer is a useful addition to clarify the implications of the word choice, however it would be improved by elaboration and citing sources if possible. It's a bit short and vague at the moment.

Comment: You also need to address the actual examples given, which don't include 'not ever'. If you're claiming that one formulation adds emphasis, the exact nature of the expression becomes important.

Answer (score 0):

"I can't ever and I can never" are the same and used interchangebly. Their meaning is the person never does that action, or he never repeats it. Just no hope at all.

Comment: You contrast "I can't ever" and "I can never". But the OP contrasts "I can't ever win" and "I can never win". One issue you don't address is that "I can never win" can be parsed as "I can [never win]". Parsed that way, "I can never" is not a constituent.

Answer (score 0):

In the meaning that you probably intend, 1. is your better choice because it is the action of the active verb (can) that is negated.

Not, ever, and never are all adverbs

## In broad terms:

In sentences with a modal verb, "not" follows - and negates - the modal verb (because that is the active verb). But "never" precedes the verbs it qualifies it -"I **never can** win." > "I can **never win**."

Compare

He can see the ship.

He can not see the ship.

These comment on his **ability** to see the ship.

He can always **see** the ship.

He can never **see** the ship.

These comment on his ability **to see**. (He might [always] be able to hear or smell the ship.)

In your example:

1 I can **never** win. = I am able **{at no time to win}**. – My **winning** is impossible – the “never” qualifies “win”

2 I **can't** ever win. = I **can not** ever win. = I **{am not able}** at any time to win. – My **ability** is lacking. The “not” qualifies “can”.

Compare with

I {can easily} win -> My winning {will be done without much effort.}

I can {win easily} -> My ability is such that {I can beat the others by a large margin.}

Comment: Doesn't "I am able {at no time to win}" rather mean "My **not** **winning** is possible"? That is, you have the ability to act in such a way that you don't win?

Comment: The nuance is subtle, but the answer to your question is "No." We must concentrate on which verb (the modal or the infinitive) is negated.

Comment: I thought that that was the point of your distinction: that in your 1., "win" is negated, so the sentence means that I have the ability to not win ever; in your 2., "can" is negated, so the sentence means that I forever lack the ability to win. Have I misunderstood you?

Comment: In the examples, not follows, and qualifies, "can". "Never" precedes, and qualifies, "win". "Can not" emphasises the inability; "never win" emphasises the impossibility of winning.